# Eliminating unnecessary parts from a JSON

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a pretty complicated JSON file that I encourage you to copy-paste [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#) for better visualization.

```
{
  "data":[
    {
      "title":"Title1",
      "paragraphs":[
        {
          "context":"Context1",
          "qas":[
            {
             "answers":[
               {
                "answer_start":515,
                "text":"String text"
               }
              ],
             "question": "Why something something?",
             "id":"5733be284776f41900661182"
             },
             {
             "answers":[
               {
                "answer_start":505,
                "text":"String something text"
               }
              ],
             "question": "Why?",
             "id":"5733be284776f4190066345"
             }
            ]
           },
           {
          "context":"Context2",
          "qas":[
            {
             "answers":[
               {
                "answer_start":515,
                "text":"String text"
               }
              ],
             "question": "Why something something?",
             "id":"5733be284776f41900661182"
             },
             {
             "answers":[
               {
                "answer_start":505,
                "text":"String something text"
               }
              ],
             "question": "Why?",
             "id":"5733be284776f4190066345"
             }
            ]
           }
          ]
         },
         {
         "title":"Title2",
      "paragraphs":[
        {
          "context":"Context10",
          "qas":[
            {
             "answers":[
               {
                "answer_start":585,
                "text":"String text"
               }
              ],
             "question": "Why something something?",
             "id":"5733be284776f41900661682"
             },
             {
             "answers":[
               {
                "answer_start":545,
                "text":"String something text"
               }
              ],
             "question": "Why?",
             "id":"5733be284776f41900663"
             }
            ]
           },
           {
          "context":"Context7",
          "qas":[
            {
             "answers":[
               {
                "answer_start":525,
                "text":"String text"
               }
              ],
             "question": "Why something something?",
             "id":"5733be284776f41982"
             },
             {
             "answers":[
               {
                "answer_start":595,
                "text":"String something text"
               }
              ],
             "question": "Why?",
             "id":"5733be284776f419005"
             }
            ]
           }
          ]
         }
         ],
          "version":"1.1"
         }
```

I don't need all this information and I want my data format to look simpler, like this:

```
[
 {
   "id": "5733be284776f41900661182",
   "context": "Context1",
   "question": "Why something something?",
   "answers": {"text": ["String text"]}
 },
 {
    "id": "5733be284776f4190066345",
    "context": "Context1",
    "question": "Why?",
    "answers": {"text": ["String something text"]}
 },
 {
   "id": "5733be284776f41900661182",
   "context": "Context2",
   "question": "Why something something?",
   "answers": {"text": ["String text"]}
 },
 {
    "id": "5733be284776f4190066345",
    "context": "Context2",
    "question": "Why?",
    "answers": {"text": ["String something text"]}
 },
 {
   "id": "5733be284776f41900661682",
   "context": "Context10",
   "question": "Why something something?",
   "answers": {"text": ["String text"]}
 },
 {
    "id": "5733be284776f41900663",
    "context": "Context10",
    "question": "Why?",
    "answers": {"text": ["String something text"]}
 },
 {
   "id": "5733be284776f41982",
   "context": "Context7",
   "question": "Why something something?",
   "answers": {"text": ["String text"]}
 },
 {
    "id": "5733be284776f419005",
    "context": "Context7",
    "question": "Why?",
    "answers": {"text": ["String something text"]}
 }                                                                                                                                  
]
```

I don't care about the paragraphs, titles, answer start etc., and I would prefer it if the contexts were separated. Is there any way one can turn such a JSON into something much simpler? What I tried was to remove the unnecessary words in Python (replace them with `" "`), but it made a mess out of it. I also tried to open it as a dataframe and remove the columns, but there are many nested things that I want removed too.

Comment: @BrutusForcus sorry, I did, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a simple Python script to translate this format:

```
import json

with open('file.json', 'r') as fh:
    data = json.load(fh)

result = []

for article in data["data"]:
    for paragraph in article["paragraphs"]:
        for qa in paragraph["qas"]:
            answers = {"text": [answer["text"] for answer in qa["answers"]]}
            result.append({
                "id": qa["id"], 
                "context": paragraph["context"], 
                "question": qa["question"], 
                "answers": answers
            })

with open('output.json', 'w') as fh:
    json.dump(result, fh)
```

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense, however I get a syntax error at `with open`... I checked the file path and they are correct, it all works up to there. Whereby this is not tragic because I can just print the output, but the original file is huge.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a bracket. I corrected it in my answer.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see it either! Thank you! I have an extra question though, if you don't mind: how come the original file is much smaller than the one that your code outputs, since we deleted stuff out of it? My OG file has 30MB and the new one 80MB, how is this possible? Sorry if it is a bit offtopic.

Comment: I honestly don't know. Shouldn't be so much of a difference, I guess. The result of the example file you provided was about half size compared to the input. Can you open and check the result file by yourself and try to figure out why?

Comment: I did, the output is alrght, valid and complete. I think the reason is because the same context appears every time I have this question-answer pair, and not just once.

Comment: Yes, but it should not result into that much of a difference, I guess, unless your context strings are very long or you have a lot QA pairs. You can verify this guess by removing "context" from the script and compare the resulting file size with the previous ones.